# Why The Validation is not working for the provided html/ js code

Tags: javascript, html

I want the to get the required in the html page if none is selected.

```js
function validation() {
  var country = getElementById("country");
  if (country.value = "") {
    documnet.getElementById("countryy").innerHTML = "Required";
    return false;
  } else
    return true;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validation();">

  <select id="country"><span id="countryy"></span>

  </select><br>

  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Why The Validation is not working for the provided html/ js code. I want the to get the required in the html page if none is selected. I am new to js learning.

Answer (score 3):

Several issues

1. Spelling mistake in the `document.getElementById`
2. missing document on the other `document.getElementById`
3. No preventDefault which will submit the form if any JS errors
4. = is assignment - you need == or === to compare
5. span needs to be outside the select
6. You did not use value="Default" in the "NONE" options

It is not recommended to have inline event handlers. Here is a better version

Note I added a class to toggle the required in case the user changes the select to conform

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const errorSpan = document.getElementById("countryy"); // cache the elements
  const country = document.getElementById("country");
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    const val = country.value; // get the value
    if (val === "") {
      e.preventDefault(); // stop submit
    }
    errorSpan.classList.toggle("hide",val); // hide if value
  })
  country.addEventListener("change",function() { // if user changes the select
    errorSpan.classList.toggle("hide",this.val); // hide if value
  })
})
```

```css
.hide { display : none; }
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <select id="country">
    <option value="">NONE</option>
    <option value="ABDUL">ABDUL</option>
    <option value="SULE">SULE</option>
  </select> <span id="countryy" class="hide">Required</span><br>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

HOWEVER you could remove all the script and just add `required` attribute to the select and keep the empty default

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <select id="country" required>
    <option value="">NONE</option>
    <option value="ABDUL">ABDUL</option>
    <option value="SULE">SULE</option>
  </select><span id="countryy"></span><br>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why is that redundant and of no use if OP wants to handle the required themselves????

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Please see update. I added more features based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

Use required attribute in the select tag. It will considered in html 5 validation.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_select_required

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See my answer